# Why is my second array not being fully printed out?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

I’m trying to create a representation of the following numbers in a column and row.

Why is my second array not being fully printed out?

Also, the numbers aren’t being printed in a row and column fashion. Why is this?

```
public class MultidimensionalArrays
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    //initializes rows and columns
    //first box = row, second box = column
    int firstarray[][] = {{3, 4, 5, 6,} , {8, 9}};

    //System.out.println(firstarray[0][1]) = 9;

    //initializes another rows and columns
    int secondarray[][] = {{11, 12, 13} , {88} , {100, 200, 300} , {33, 35, 37}};

    //displays the 1st array
    System.out.println("this is the 1st array: ");
    display(firstarray);

    System.out.println();

    //displays the 2nd array
    System.out.println("this is the 2nd array: ");
    display(secondarray);
}

//makes a method to display out the arrays
public static void display(int x[][])
{
    //makes a for-loop that prints out the row
    for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++)
    {
        //makes a for-loop that prints out the column
        for(int column = 0; column < x.length; column++)
        {
            //sysouts the rows & columns
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
    }
}


}
```

Error code:

```
this is the 1st array: 
3   4   8   9   
this is the 2nd array: 
11  12  13  Exception in thread "main"           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at MultidimensionalArrays.display(MultidimensionalArrays.java:37)
at MultidimensionalArrays.main(MultidimensionalArrays.java:24)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not a matrix, so column length is not equal to row length. In fact, different rows have different number of columns, so you must use the individual length of each row.

Try :

```
for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++)
{
    //makes a for-loop that prints out the column
    for(int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++)
    {
        //sysouts the rows & columns
        System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the number of rows to print the columns. These obviously don't match in your test case. Modify like this

```
//makes a for-loop that prints out the row
for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++)
{
    //makes a for-loop that prints out the column
    for(int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++)
    {
        //sysouts the rows & columns
        System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You should probably also print a new line after each row. I added the code for that.